# Is "assignment" the same as "a job"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, usage

Yourdictionary.com and couple of others provide this definition for "assignment":

> A position or post of duty to which one is assigned.
> *The journalist took an assignment in China.*

Is this the same as "a job"? Does the sentence mean that the journalist took a job in China?

Some other definitions state that it's:

> A piece of work that has been assigned (source [thefreedictionary](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.thefreedictionary.com/&ved=2ahUKEwiBn9eMg6j4AhUa63MBHa83D-sQFnoECAUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1As_FP1AojyxpF54R2FV4q))

Is assignment not only a piece of work but also your occupation? Something you do for a living. Can I say "My assignment for the last 20 years was a taxi driver"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can say it if you wish but it would be misleading unless someone had assigned you to be a taxi driver, which would be most unlikely.

A **job** is a description of any kind of work a person or organisation undertakes, whether paid or unpaid.

An **assignment** is of its nature usually a temporary function/commission/appointment in which somebody is sent to do a particular job for a time.

If you are for example an accountant, you can be assigned to a particular desk or account; a policeman to a particular investigation, a soldier to a particular unit, a banker to a particular branch - and so on.

In all these cases, somebody senior assigns someone more junior to do the job.

So, in your example, the journalist undertook a particular job in China to either report on or investigate or follow up a story.

Comment: Additionally, at school an *assignment* is a specific task for a student to do in class time or as homework, and the word also refers to the document which is produced during the assignment and handed in for correction. On the other hand a *job* is a task unrelated to the students studies, for example rubbish bin duty.

Comment: Also, a 'job' can be a position in which one is employed, e.g. police officer, journalist, and also a task imposed in that employment, e.g. patrolling a stretch of road, writing a story, and so on. This latter meaning can be synonymous with 'assignment'.